# How to implement ASyncTask in my code

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

in my app I am trying to read a string out of a text file located online, and then save the contents to a variable. Here is my current code:

```
        download.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                URL site = new URL("http://m.uploadedit.com/b029/1393133970157.txt");
                Scanner s = new Scanner(site.openStream());
                String num = s.nextLine();
            }
            catch(MalformedURLException e) { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }
            catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();            
            }                    

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "String from file is: " + num,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

        }
    });
```

However this is giving me a force close. Here is the log: http://pastebin.com/2nsxmJz1
I believe that I need to implement an ASyncTask, but not sure how to go about doing so.

Comment: You could try using Google to find the docs or a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use network communications on UI thread. As u correctly mentions you should use `AsyncTask` for such cases:

```
final AsyncTask<Object,Object,String> task = new AsyncTask<Object,Object,String>() {
   protected String doInBackground(Object... o) {
        try {
            URL site = new URL("http://m.uploadedit.com/b029/1393133970157.txt");
            Scanner s = new Scanner(site.openStream());
            return s.nextLine();
        }
        catch(MalformedURLException e) { 
            throw new RuntimeException("Incorrect URL", e);
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Can't fetch file content from url", e);
        }   
   }

   protected void onPostExecute(String r) {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "String from file is: " + r,
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
   }
};
task.execute();
```

Comment: Thanks, so would this still go inside of my onclicklistener?

Comment: Ok Ive put it in the onclicklistener but now ive got an error saying: "The type new AsyncTask<Object,Object,String>(){} must implement the inherited abstract method AsyncTask<Object,Object,String>.doInBackground(Object...)". I believe i need to extend the ASyncTask in my class, but my class already extends Activity so I cant do it.

Comment: Are you calling `new AsyncTask().execute();` on your `onCreate()`?

Comment: Yes, you can call this directly from `OnClickListener`. See edits... You should specify `doInBackground(Object... o)` instead of `doInBackground(Object o)`. My bad, sorry